# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' message on Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, video.js

We are using [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) with the [youtube plugin](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube).

When loading a video I am getting error showed in the console.

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://www.youtube.com').
```

I followed the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/67) and added forceSSL:true, which fixed the problem for desktop but I am still getting it on the android devices.

**videoJS instance creation:**

```
scope.player = videojs('vid3', { techOrder: ["youtube"], controls: true, preload: "auto", autoplay: false, 'forceSSL':true, 'forceHTML5':true, src: attributes.src})
```

Comment: I have submitted a bug...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are loading the page inside a **WebView**. Which method are you using?
I suggest you to use the method [loadDataWithBaseURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) passing *http://www.youtube.com* as **baseUrl**.

As written in the docs:

> loadDataWithBaseURL loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL
>   for the content. The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs
>   and when applying JavaScript's same origin policy.